# folder in github repo. can't be opened

Tags: github

After push my project to github server, I see this on one of my folders:

[image]

The taintgraph folder can't be opened, and has a commit number followed by.

Could someone explain what is going on?

Thansk!

Comment: https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/ ?

Comment: Check if you don't have a hidden .git folder in the traingraph folder